# How to obtain URL referral link prior to redirection?

Tags: redirect, phpmyadmin, registration

This is just a simple referral website.

I need help creating the referring structure. I have done the registration part - the registration page automatically generates referring URL for new user and store them in the database.

Is there a way to get the user referring website or link to be precise as I had setup my home page as the 404 error page so that everybody visiting the website/user link get redirects to the homepage.

In other words, is there anyway I get can the original link they follow to get to my website before they are redirected to my home page?

I also set the redirection in my .htaccess files.

I have tried using `$_GET parameters` to no avail and I also tried getting their `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERAL" ]` and it also wasn't successful either please is there any other work around.

Comment: Kindly improve the formatting and provide more information in your question. Adding pieces of code and information about what you have tried so far would help people answer the question more accurately too. I am editing the title for you, hope that helps you understand how to put it more aptly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make three corrections to your code.The first one is that do not set the redirection in your .htaccess files but instead use javascript redirection.
(2)Make an ajax call as soon as the user land on your webpage that will store their referal link in your database
(3)Only redirect user when the ajax call resolve successfully.